# bash iteration over paired data

Tags: bash, loops

I have a program executed from a bash script

`mydata=$(myprogram etc)`

which delivers data like this:

`echo $mydata`

`foo1`

`bar1`

`foo2`

`bar2`

...

`foo_n`

`bar_n`

I would like to iterate over `$mydata` delivering to another command like this:

`another_command foo1 bar1`

Question:  how can I do this with bash?  Question 2: Would delivering the data another way greatly simplify things? For example if the data looked like this:

`foo1 bar1 foo2 bar2 ... foo_n bar_n`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `xargs` command

```
 echo $mydata | xargs -n 2 another_command
```

For example:

```
 $ echo foo1 bar1 foo2 bar2 | xargs -n 2 echo PAIR
 PAIR foo1 bar1
 PAIR foo2 bar2
```

It does not matter for `xargs` with the default options if the input is separated by spaces or newlines

Answer (score 2):

You can use this script:

```
while read a; read b; do 
   another_command "$a" "$b"
done < file
```

Comment: You can also simply read 2 lines at a time: `while read foo; read bar; do another_command "$foo" "$bar"; done < file`.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks, yes that will be better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use array

declare array

```
declare -a mydata
```

then save the output to array, run the command between ***(*** and ***)***

```
mydata=( $(echo -e "f1\nb1\nf2\nb2") )
       ^                             ^
```

and

```
for (( i=0;$i<${#mydata[*]};i+=2 ))
do
   echo ${mydata[$i]}" "${mydata[$i+1]}
done
```